# The scroll bar has problems, displaying a smaller bar if the screen pixel is smaller

Tags: html, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIzzS.png)

I put this logic in to fix it but it didn't work, nor did it change anything on the screen

```
  <app-titulo-pagina [titulo]="'Solicitações de pedidos'"></app-titulo-pagina>

<section>
 
  <app-default-loading [condicao]="this.loading"></app-default-loading>  
    <div *ngIf="!this.loading">
    
      <section tourAnchor="tour-list-pedidos">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
          <table id="pedidos"   *ngIf="this.dtOptions.data" datatable [dtOptions]="this.dtOptions"></table>
        </div>
          
      </section>    
      <app-pagina-sem-informacao *ngIf="!this.dtOptions.data" mensagem="Nenhuma solicitação de serviço foi encontrada!"></app-pagina-sem-informacao>
    </div> 
</section>

That yellow bar shouldn't exist, how do I fix it by inserting a div?
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML as well, we cannot guess what your structure is if you do not help us to do so